# Importing error in python using eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, import

I have two files one is:

- `file1.py` that is located at `myapp/file1.py`
- `file2.py` at `test/file2.py`

I want to use the function of `file2.py` in `file1.py`

How can i import `file2.py` to `file1.py`?

I tried to: `from test.file2 import file2` it compiles but when i run it i got an error from the debug: `Import Error no module named file2`
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

By Default, Python searches in the project directory and hence the files from other directories cannot be imported as we do for the files available locally in the project folder.

But to accomplish that we might want to amend the system path which can be done in the following way.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/your/filefolder/')
#also sys.path.append(0,/'path/to/your/filefolder/[file])
import [your file]
```

Hope this can help :)

Comment: Alternatively run the program as ```python -m myapp.file1``` from the folder above myapp. Not sure about how convenient that is to do in Eclipse though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but, I solve it by creating it as a package (by creating __init__.py file).